# converting digits to word in string in python

Tags: python, for-loop, scripting, alphanumeric

```
> #!/usr/bin/env python
> 
> import inflect
> 
> p = inflect.engine() 
s1 = ''
> 
>         word = 'so do 1st or do 2nd or 3rd byte 4 th so do 5th longest word 3765 word 50 but 7th'
>     list_word = list(word)
>     print (list_word)
>     
>     for(m= 0; m <list_word.len(); m++):
>            if list_word[m].isalpha():
>                    s1 += i + ''
>            elif list_word[m].isnumeric():
>                    if (list_word[m+1].isnumeric()):
>                            continue
>                    elif (list_word[m+1]+list_word[m+2] == 'st'):
>                            s1 += first + ''
>                            m += 2
>                    elif (list_word[m+1]+list_word[m+2] == 'nd'):
>                            s1 += second + ''
>                            m += 2
>                    elif (list_word[m+1]+list_word[m+2] == 'rd'):
>                            s1 += third + ''
>                            m += 2
>                    elif (list_word[m+1]+list_word[m+2] == 'th'):
>                            if (list_word[m] == '5'):
>                                  s1 += fifth + ''
>                                  m += 2
>                            else :
>                                  s1 += p.number_to_words(list_word[m]) + ''
>                                  m += 2
>                    elif (list_word[m+1].isnumeric()):
>                            continue
>                    else:
>                            s1 += p.number_to_words(list_word[m]) + ''
>            else:
>                    s1 += ' '
>
```

I need to convert digits to word and make a complete string with alphabets only. But the issue is this kind of **for loop** can not be used in **Python** and i need to **iterate to next to next character** at some places. Can I get any suggestions regarding this, please.
Or if someone can suggest any other approach.

Comment: perhaps ```for m in list_word:```?  or if you need index values, ```for m in range(len(list_word)):```

Comment: I tried but looks like my code gets, more complicated by the way I was approaching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [`num2words`](https://pypi.org/project/num2words/) package we can do do this to translate the whole string without any for-loops:

```
import re
import num2words

def transInt(num, mode=None):
    # Changes the mode of the translation to 
    # correctly translate ordinal numbers.
    if mode:
        mode = "ordinal"
    else:
        mode = "cardinal"

    # translates the number to either float
    # or int, so the translation works correctly.
    if "." in num:
        num = float(num)
    else:
        num = int(num)
    return num2words.num2words(num, to=mode)

def replaceInt(string):
    # Matches numbers, followed by optional ordinal-characters after it.
    return re.sub(r"(\d+\.*\d*)(st|nd|rd|th)*", lambda x: transInt(*x.groups()), string)

word = 'so do 1st or do 2nd or 3rd byte 4th so do 5th longest word 3765 word 50 but 7th'
print(word)
print(replaceInt(word))
```

Output:

```
so do 1st or do 2nd or 3rd byte 4th so do 5th longest word 3765 word 50 but 7th
so do first or do second or third byte fourth so do fifth longest word three thousand, seven hundred and sixty-five word fifty but seventh
```

The important thing with the translation is that the suffix ("th" in 5th) is connected to the number. In your example you have `"4 th"` which will not work with my code. Or rather, it will translate `4` as `four` instead of `fourth`

Comment: Thank you Sir, it's working perfectly. I will explore this method further as it seems very useful

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way would be to use a while loop instead and manually iterate the variable. For example:

```
m = 0
while m < len(list_word):
   body
   final else
      
   m += 1
```

In effect this is the same as using the for loop like you are